# Convert DateTime in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, datetime

I need to convert the Current date time into `"04/10/2013 12:00:00 GMT+5:00"` format.
I had gone through differet methods but couldn't got the exact format.
Can anyone know please help me.

Comment: can you provide some code stuff please.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-datetime.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// String To Date Conversion
NSString *dateStr = @"5/13/2012 6:05 am";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm a"];
NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];

// This converts time to GMT local timezone    
NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
// calculate Number of seconds upto 5hrs(GMT+5000) seconds = 18000, if its GMT+0530 then seconds = 19800
// Set TimeZone Accordingly
[df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:18000]];
// Set your Date Formate
[df_local setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];

// Your Final Output String
NSString* ts_local_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[df_local stringFromDate:myDate],[[df_local timeZone] name]];
NSLog(@"Final string : %@",ts_local_string);

NSString* anotherFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[df_local stringFromDate:myDate],[[df_local timeZone] abbreviation]];
NSLog(@"OUtput : %@",anotherFormat);
```

**OUTPUT : Final string : 05/13/2012 05:35:00 GMT+0500**

Comment: how to get time zone as GMT+05:00 instead of GMT+0500

Comment: i have edited answer with your required format check it, let me know insights.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date]; 
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"];
NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

This will be in 12 hour format. If you want 24 hour format replace hh with HH.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM, dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
```